# Frac$(R)=F$, quotient field of the integral domain $R$, then Frac$(R[x]) \cong F(x)$ and also Frac$(R[x]) \cong F(x_{1},x_{2},....,x_{n})$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $R$ be an integral domain, and consider $\operatorname{Frac}(R)=F$ the quotient field of $D$. Then $\operatorname{Frac}(R[x]) \cong F(x)$ and also $\operatorname{Frac}(R[x]) \cong F(x_{1},x_{2},....,x_{n})$.

For the first part of the statement, as $\operatorname{Frac}(R)= \lbrace ab^{-1} /  a,b \in R\rbrace$, so more than an isomorphism, I think this problem as an equality, so I need to see that if $p(x) \in \operatorname{Frac}(R[x])$ if and only if $p(x)= \frac{q(x)}{r(x)}$ with $q(x), r(x) \in R[x]$ and also show that $p(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}) \in \operatorname{Frac}(R[x_{1},...x_{n}])$ if and only if $p(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n})= \frac{q(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n})}{r(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n})}$ with $q(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}), r(x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}) \in F(x_{1},...,x_{n})$? If this way is right then Im supposed to use that every coefficient of $p(x) \in F(x)$ is also in $\operatorname{Frac}(R)$? Thanks

Comment: Do you know the universal property of localization?

Comment: Also what is the difference between $D$ and $R$? And you probably mean "integral domain" not "integer domain".

Comment: D=R, already corrected that. Yes, I'm thinking how to use universal property here :/ @B.Swan

Comment: Also do you mean $R[x_1, x_2,...] \cong F(x_1, x_2, ...)$? Or is what you have written correct?

Comment: It is well written. @B.Swan

Comment: Any hint about how to apply universal property of localization here?

Answer (score 2):

Hint for the first part:

Consider the ring homomorphisms:

$$f: R[X] \rightarrow F(X), p \mapsto \frac{p}{1}$$

$$i: R[X] \rightarrow Frac(R[X]), p \mapsto p$$

$$f': Frac(R[X]) \rightarrow F(X), pq^{-1} \mapsto \frac{p}{q}$$

Note that $f = f' \circ i$.

You need to show that those are indeed ring homomorphisms and that $f'$ is well-defined, surjective an injective. Remember that since $R$ is an integral domain, so is $R[X]$, and thus $Frac(R[X])$ is a field, and ring homomorphisms between fields are injective.

You should know that $i$ is a ring homomorphism from the universal property of localization. $i$ is also injective onto $Frac(R[X])$, since $R[X]$ is an intergral domain and does not contain zero divisors.

Also if $f$ and $f'$ are ring homomorphisms, then then $f'$ is unique.

---

For the second part we already know that $Frac(R[X])≅F(X)$ and by the thread posted in the comments you know that $R[X_1, X_2, ..., X_n] \cong S[X]$, where $S=R[X_1, X_2, ..., X_{n-1}]$.

We also know that if $R$ was an integral domain $R[X]$ is an integral domain. So $S$ will be an integral domain too, and we can use our base argument.

So $Frac(R[X_1, ... X_n]) \cong Frac(S[X]) \cong F_S(X) $, where $F_S=Frac(S)$ by the base case. Can you show that this is isomorphic to $F(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n)$?

Note that $F_S(X)$ are fractions of functions dependant on $X$ with coefficients in $S=R[X_1, ..., X_{n-1}]$ and $F(X_1, ..., X_n)$ are fractions of functions in $n$ variables. Why are they the same?

Comment: Thanks a lot! But It shouldnt be $f':F[X] \to Frac(R[x])$ instead of $f':Frac(R[x]) \to F(X)$? Also if this is true how the correspondece change? Also how this idea can be generalized into $n$ terms polynomials? @B.Swan

Comment: Look at this diagram, here is how the morphisms commute: https://i.imgur.com/coDh0Y8.png, I have written it wrong, and will correct it.

Comment: As to the second one: look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/717298/show-that-the-polynomial-ring-in-n-1-variables-is-isomorphic-to-the-polynomial, I do not think what you have written in your post does not hold. You want polynomials in one variable to be isomorphic to ones in many.

Comment: There are some flaws in my question, yes. What I meant as the second statement is how I prove that $Frac(R[x_{1},....x_{n}]) \cong F(x_{1},....,x_{n})$? Im thinking in an inductive proof but Im not sure. :/  @B.Swan

Comment: Yes, look at the question I have posted in my last comment and use that for induction.

Comment: The proof will be: If $Frac(R[x_{1}]) \cong F(x_{1})$ by induction basis, by induction hypothesis we have $Frac(R[x_{1},...x_{n-1}]) \cong F(x_{1},....,x_{n-1})$ so, as $ F(x_{1},....,x_{n-1},x_{n}) \cong F(x_{1},....,x_{n-1}) \cong Frac(R[x_{1},...x_{n-1}]) \cong Frac(R[x_{1},...x_{n-1},x_{n}])$ ???  @B.Swan

Comment: Not quite correct, see my edit!

Comment: Still not sure why the last isomorphism $Frac(S[X])≅FS(X)$? And to conclude the proof $Frac(S) \cong F(x_{1},....x_{n-1}) \cong F(x_{1},...,x_{n})$? @B.Swan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90975/discussion-between-b-swan-and-cos).